# error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Currently I am trying to use a `std::unique_ptr`, but I'm getting a compiler error in Visual Studio 2012.

```
class A
{
private:
 unique_ptr<A> other;
public:
 unique_ptr<A> getOther()
 {
   return other;
 }
};
```

And the error is:

```
error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
with
[
    _Ty=A
]
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(1447) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr'
with
[
    _Ty=A
]
```

Comment: You cannot copy unique_ptr because... they're unique. (Hint: you're returning the pointer by value, which makes a copy)

Comment: Why are you using `unique_ptr` if you want multiple copies?

Comment: Ok... I got confused with the error. Now I got the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `std::unique_ptr` can be a return type, if the value that is returned is of local scope (i.e., it gets destroyed as soon as it gets out of the function). In your case it's not, since you are returning `unique_ptr<A> other`, which has life time while the class is valid.