# Error c2248 when exporting a class that has a private member of type std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stack, unique-ptr

Why do I get this error:

```
Error   2   error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0 606 1   UNIQUE_PTR
```

when trying to Export this class with `__declspec(dllexport)`?

```
class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
private:
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<int>> ints;
};
```

Im using vs2012

Comment: Can't tell really, I guess because whoever is trying to access `ints` doesn't have access rights, cause is private.

Comment: Its all the code I compile besides a main that Returns 0. I dont instantiate that class, I do nothing with it

Comment: I would try using a new compiler.  MSVS 2012 is not C++11 compliant.  If you have to stay in the MSVS world then I would try MSVS 2015.

Comment: Ok, I have vs2013 installed at home, ill try it.

Comment: I would use GCC  5.x but I cant seem to get it to run on Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Visual Studio so I can't be sure of the meaning of the error message, but I can see that your class is unusable: the only member variable is private, and you wrote no methods to access it.

Comment: Added a function, still get the error. Btw I have a much larger class in a different Project that compiles fine until I add a private member of type std::stack<std::unique_ptr<T>>, but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: What function exactly? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441287/error-c2248-cannot-access-private-member-declared-in-class, probable duplicate question

Comment: I am **not** trying to Access that member. I know I have to use an accessor to Access it from outside the class.

Comment: ... and also to avoid this error I think. Write a setter and a getter and see what happens.

Comment: Anyway, this may be related to unique_ptr, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871247/error-c2248-stdunique-ptr-tyunique-ptr-cannot-access-private-member-d?rq=1

Comment: I dont even want to access that member from outside the class I just want to push/Pop items to/from it, also it says "cannot access private member **IN** class **std::unique_ptr<_Ty>**". So its definetely not complaining about me trying to access the private member.

Comment: I read the question and I totally understand I should not return a COPY of a UNIQUE_ptr, but im not doing that in my code...

Comment: I get the same warning message just by using `std::stack<int> ints`. So I don't think it is related to `unique_ptr`. I'v been reading this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958 but no result so far.

Comment: Upgrade your compiler, the only solution to this nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand std::stack assumes that the elements can be **copied**, which is not true for the std::unique_ptr, which has to be **moved**.

So the problem is that std::stack cannot access the private copy constructor of the std::unique_ptr, not that std::stack is private itself.

Comment: But I read in multiple places that using std::unique_ptr with stl Containers is supposed to work... And I am more than sure that I already got sth like that to work

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168958 you might have some difficulties exporting `stack` and `unique_ptr`. (Since `stack` uses `deque`)

> Some STL classes contain nested classes. These classes can not be
>   exported. For instance, deque contains a nested class deque::iterator.
>   If you export deque, you will get a warning that you must export
>   deque::iterator. If you export deque::iterator, you get a warning that
>   you must export deque. This is caused by a designed limitation that
>   once a template class is instantiated, it can not be re-instantiated
>   and exported. **The only STL container that can currently be exported
>   is vector. The other containers (that is, map, set, queue, list,
>   deque) all contain nested classes and cannot be exported.**

Comment: I tried the same code without the std::unique_ptr<T>, so just std::stack<int> and it works fine. I can push/Pop to/from the stack without a Problem.